object in xml file does not remove as expected
I want to delet the fllowing tag from the xml file.
I try in two ways, del and gc and its not deleted.
xml file:
<homework name = "stam">
    <subject>
        math
    </subject>
    <date>
        <year>
        2025
        </year>
        <day>
        16.5
        </day>
        <day>
        5.3
        </day>
    </date>
</homework>

python file:
del root[1][1]
print(root[1][1])
import gc
gc.collect()
print(root[1][1])

the disply:
<Element 'day' at 0x0000016D7B562D40>
<Element 'day' at 0x0000016D7B562D40>

why its not working?

How is root created?

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("data_store.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

There are two day elements, you delete one with del. gc.collect() does nothing relevant here.

but its not deleted. i can still approach he elemnt. <Element 'day' at 0x0000016D7B562D40>

How do you know that this is the first day element?

Because that's what I approached

del root[1][1]
print(root[1][1])
import gc
gc.collect()
print(root[1][1])

Maybe it deleted the next 'day' element for me?
If so, why?

I don't understand. How can you identify which of the two day elements is printed? To do that you can e. g. print(root[1][1]) before deletion and after and compare the address (the 0x000... part).

In your code, you use del root[1][1] to delete the second <day> element under <date>. But del is not always a good thing. The reason for this is that this may not work as expected because the indexing may not be correct. Instead, you can use XPath to find the item you want to delete and then remove it.
Here is solution for your code.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_str = '''
<homework name="stam">
    <subject>
        math
    </subject>
    <date>
        <year>
            2025
        </year>
        <day>
            16.5
        </day>
        <day>
            5.3
        </day>
    </date>
</homework>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

day_to_remove = root.find(".//date/day[2]")

if day_to_remove is not None:
    root.find(".//date").remove(day_to_remove)

ET.dump(root)

Output is
<homework name="stam">
    <subject>   
        math    
    </subject>  
    <date>      
        <year>  
            2025
        </year> 
        <day>   
            16.5
        </day>
        </date>
</homework>


del root[1][1] deletes the second element in <date> which is the first day element.

I don’t understood your point, it works as expected. Root[1][1] is the day tag with 16.6:

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_s="""
<homework name = "stam">
    <subject>
        math
    </subject>
    <date>
        <year>
        2025
        </year>
        <day>
        16.5
        </day>
        <day>
        5.3
        </day>
    </date>
</homework>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_s)

ET.indent(root, space='  ')
ET.dump(root)

print("delete second element with text:", root[1][1].text)
del root[1][1]

ET.dump(root)

Output:

<homework name="stam">
  <subject>
        math
    </subject>
  <date>
    <year>
        2025
        </year>
    <day>
        16.5
        </day>
    <day>
        5.3
        </day>
  </date>
</homework>
delete second element with text: 
        16.5
        
<homework name="stam">
  <subject>
        math
    </subject>
  <date>
    <year>
        2025
        </year>
    <day>
        5.3
        </day>
  </date>
</homework>

